# How to update a field while creating a new post with ACF form

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'm using an ACF Form in the front-end of a WordPress website. The ACF form in 'Post A' creates a new post 'Post B'. I am trying to create a function that will update an ACF field in Post A (I will then use this to remove the form from Post A so that it can only be submitted once). I have been trying to use an acf/save_post action to update the field but this seems to only effect Post B and not Post A. Here is my code:

```
<?php 
add_action('acf/save_post', 'update_post_status', 20);

function update_post_status( $post_id ) {

    if( get_post_type($post_id) !== 'mypost' ) {
        return;
    }
  
    update_field('form_submitted', 'yes');
  
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive had success with using `acf/validate_save_post` rather than `acf/save_post` as this fires before the new post is created so the function still refers to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you use the incorrect hook for this task

[acf-save_post](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/)

```
Fires when saving the submitted $_POST data.
```

You can use '[save_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/)'

```
Save_post is an action triggered whenever a post or page is created or updated, which could be from an import, post/page edit form, xmlrpc, or post by email. The data for the post is stored in $_POST, $_GET or the global $post_data, depending on how the post was edited. For example, quick edits use $_POST.
```

For example

```php
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_post_function', 10, 3 );

function my_save_post_function( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
    if( get_post_type($post_ID) !== 'mypost' ) {
        return;
    }
  
    update_field('form_submitted', 'yes', $post_ID);
}
```

Comment: This seems to perform the same function of updating Post B rather than Post A. It also runs on back-end saves as well as form submissions, which may cause some problems.